# what's the difference/relationship between ptregs_execve and sys_execve

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, execve, user-mode-linux

I'm hooking system calls on Linux 2.6.32 x86-32.

However, I find that in the [system call table](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/um/sys-i386/sys_call_table.S), `__NR_execve` is pointing to `ptregs_execve` rather than `sys_execve`. And, I can't find the function definition of `ptregs_execve` anywhere.

Can anyone help me clarify the difference or relationship between `ptregs_execve` and sys_execve? I know for the [um](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) architecture, `ptregs_execve` is defined as `sys_execve`. How about other architectures?

Comment: Yeah. In /arch/um/sys-i386/sys_call_table.S, we can find #define ptregs_execve sys_execve.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly more helpful:

Note that the macro PTREGSCALL3 is defined in entry_32.S.   This defines a shim function that calls sys_##name.  This macro is invoked with execve as an argument.  So, ptregs_execve is simply a shim that calls sys_execve with the appropriate arguments.